# Many-to-many relation in Yii2 migration

Tags: yii2, migration, many-to-many, relation

I have 2 tables, `post` and `comment`. In Laravel I can create pivot table `comment_post` implicitly by defining relations in models. How can I do the same in Yii2?

table post:

```
  id    -- PK
  text
```

table comment:

```
  id    -- PK
  text
  user_id
```

table comment_post:

```
  id    -- PK
  post_id   -- foreign key references ID on post table
  comment_id    -- foreign key references ID on comment table
```

Comment: You need to create table `comment_post` and [addForeignKey](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#addForeignKey()-detail)

Comment: @InsaneSkull does this mean that Yii2 canont implicitly create pivot tables?

Comment: Are you talking about `hasMany` relation? Yii2 Gii can generate relations when you create model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a table called "user" with pk called "id"

From commandline make the following migrations:

```
yii migrate/create create_post_table --fields="text:text"
yii migrate/create create_comment_table --fields="text:text,user_id:integer:notNull:foreignKey(user)"
yii migrate/create create_postComment_table --fields="post_id:integer:notNull:foreignKey(post),comment_id:integer:notNull:foreignKey(comment)"
```

Then run:

```
yii migrate
```

Then use [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) to generate the active record classes, the relationships will be made automatically.
Then, for example, you can use the following syntax: `$post->comments`

More on migrations: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html

Update because of comment:

To facilitate the `$post->comments` syntax, inside your Post class you would have a function like the following:

```
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::classname(),['id'=>'comment_id'])
    ->viaTable('postComment',['post_id','id']);
}
```

Comment: Right now I cannot use gii. Is there any way to generate the relationships without gii?